# How can I use set_facts from a role with a when conditional in a delegate_to role after caching?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a set of tasks made up of individual roles that are run with 'when' conditionals to only execute on certain hosts, within them I pull specific values by using vars/set_facts that produce what I'm looking for - but the last role in the overall play is to take the results/facts from all and apply them in a Jinja HTML template.

Originally I had a mix of tasks within a role that would run against a single group that contained subgroups - these were dictated by 'when' conditionals - since that Ive split them out, made sure no var/fact was duplicated and even introduced a bridge role that takes set_facts as vars and then sets again as vars but with a delegate_to: localhost.

```
  hosts: "{{ site_code }}"
  ignore_errors: True
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:

    - name: DMVPN Primary Check
      include_role:
        name: dmvpn-primary
      when: inventory_hostname in groups['dmvpn_primary']

    - name: DMVPN Backup Check
      include_role:
        name: dmvpn-secondary
      when: inventory_hostname in groups['dmvpn_secondary']

    - name: Fact Cache
      include_role:
        name: fact-gather

    - name: HTML Report
      include_role:
        name: html-report
      run_once: true
```

When I limit to a host within a single group, the delegate_to picks that, and selects it's own facts ok, but combining multiple hosts with the {{ site_code }} var I end up with conflicts and eventually error 'AnsibleUndefinedVariable'

EDIT: Here is a snippet from the dmvpn role, fact gather role and html.j2 file showing the flow of a couple vars that eventually spit out as **fatal: [site-vpn01 -> 127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dmvpn1_host_name' is undefined"**

roles\dmvpn-primary

```
  - name: Primary Tunnel Up/Down
    vars:
      dmvpn1_tun_stat_0: "{{ dmvpn1_result.stdout[0] }}"
      dmvpn1_tun_stat_1: "{{ dmvpn1_tun_stat_0.split() }}"
      dmvpn1_tun_stat_2: "{{ dmvpn1_tun_stat_1[3] }}"
    set_fact:
      dmvpn1_tun_status: "{{ dmvpn1_tun_stat_2 }}"
      dmvpn1_hostname: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      dmvpn1_host_ip: "{{ ansible_host }}"
      cacheable: yes
```

roles\fact-gather:

```
  - name: Primary Inventory Facts
    vars:
      dmvpn1_host_name: "{{ dmvpn1_hostname }}"
      dmvpn1_host_ipv4: "{{ dmvpn1_host_ip }}"
      dmvpn1_google_dns1_icmp: "{{ dmvpn1_icmp1_loss }}"
    set_fact:
      dmvpn1_host_name: "{{ dmvpn1_host_name }}"
      dmvpn1_host_ipv4: "{{ dmvpn1_host_ipv4 }}"
      dmvpn1_google_dns1_ip: "{{ dmvpn1_google_dns1_ip }}"
      dmvpn1_google_dns1_icmp: "{{ dmvpn1_google_dns1_icmp }}"
      dmvpn1_google_dns1_status: "{{ 'SUCCESS' if ('100' in dmvpn1_google_dns1_icmp) else 'FAIL' }}"
      cacheable: yes
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
    delegate_facts: True
    when: inventory_hostname in groups['dmvpn_primary']
```

templates\html.j2:

```
    <tr>
        {% if inventory_hostname in groups['dmvpn_primary'] %}
            <td>{{ location }}</td>
            <td>{{ sitecode[2]|upper }}</td>
            <td>{{ dmvpn1_host_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ dmvpn1_host_ipv4 }}</td>
            <td>ICMP</td>
            <td>Google DNS1</td>
            <td>{{ dmvpn1_google_dns1_icmp }}%</td>
            <td>{{ dmvpn1_google_dns1_status }}</td>
            <td>
            {% if 'SUCCESS' in dmvpn1_google_dns1_status %}
             - 
            {% else %}
            {{ slack_url }}
            {% endif %}
            </td>
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
```

Comment: [hostvars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables) is probably what you're looking for. But, it's not clear from the question. Make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Put relevant pieces of the code into the question instead of descriptions.

Comment: Cheers for the writing tip, made an edit above to show a snippet of the flow of a couple vars to facts to reference. With hostvars, wouldn't it not match if say the delegate_to uses a different host in the group for passing off to 127.0.0.1, like my example above, at times for vpn01 facts it may delegate off vpn02..

Comment: Basically in the Jinja template, when I limit to vpn01 I get the vpn01 output, same for vpn02, but without a limit the delagte to will go **vpn02 -> 127.0.0.1** and the error is basically saying vpn02 doesnt have the set_fact taken from vpn01.